# How can you instantiate an inner class AND implement an additional interface

Tags: java, interface, inner-classes

I have a requirement in Java to create an inner class and have that inner class also implement an "optional" marker interface.

e.g. What I would like to be able to do is write

```
final Object obj1 = new Adapter() implements MarkerInterface {
    @Override
    public void adapterMethod() {

    }
};

final Object obj2 = new Adapter() {
    @Override
    public void adapterMethod() {

    }
};
```

I realise the above will not compile.

What approach can I take to get the desired result?

Comment: Have you considered using an annotation instead of a marker interface?

Comment: @khelwood: Excellent left-field thinking for this specific scenario...

Comment: [nested classes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) may help solve your problem.

Comment: You ask for inner classes but your code show anonymous classes, which do you require?

Comment: I was thinking inner classes and wrote anonymous examples. Having said all that I do like the idea of achieving this with an annotation although i need to use the solution in my android application so configuring an annotation processor just for this seems a lot of effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it non-anonymous:

```
private [static] class MyAdapter extends Adapter implements MarkerInterface {
    ...
}

...

MyAdapter a = new MyAdapter();
```

You can even nest this class declaration inside your method, if you really want to.

Comment: *"You can even nest this class declaration inside your method, if you really want to."* I tend to forget that, which is probably (on the whole), a good thing. :-) But *sometimes* one might actually need to do it...

Comment: Yes, I can't remember a single time where I thought it would be a good idea.

Comment: I would consider `Adapter a = new MyAdapter();`

Comment: Often I find non-anonymous inner classes clearer than anonymous classes